# Aperture crashes as soon as I open it

Tags: crash, updates, aperture

I updated to the new Version of Aperture and it crashes every single time I want to open it.

Aperture then detected that the library needs to be repaired so it does that and then still crashes.

This is the crash info:

```
Process:         Aperture [317]
Path:            /Applications/Aperture.app/Contents/MacOS/Aperture
Identifier:      com.apple.Aperture
Version:         3.4 (3.4)
Build Info:      Aperture-301036000000000~1
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [188]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-09-23 12:22:49.788 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C54)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          18520 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           34
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  814 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   11
Anonymous UUID:                     

Crashed Thread:  4  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithScheme:host:path:]: path 580972053 is not absolute.'
terminate called throwing an exception
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92f4e0a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8e2d23f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92f4de7c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b170de8 -[NSURL(NSURL) initWithScheme:host:path:] + 112
4   PrintServices                       0x000000010e7fec6d +[NSURL(ISNSURLExtensions) URLWithScheme:host:path:] + 61
5   PrintServices                       0x000000010e7febef -[NSURL(ISNSURLExtensions) URLByAppendingPathComponent:] + 127
6   FacebookPublisher                   0x000000011c0d27f2 -[ILFacebookAPIRequest graphURLRequest] + 215
7   FacebookPublisher                   0x000000011c0d2fb5 -[ILFacebookAPIRequest send] + 33
8   FacebookPublisher                   0x000000011c0c44da -[IPHFacebookPlugin displayNameForUsername:] + 88
9   AccountConfigurationPlugin          0x000000010dd04fa5 -[AccountConfigurationProfileInformationDownloadOperation main] + 174
10  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b1c7986 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 684
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b1cf1a1 __block_global_6 + 129
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff898aff01 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff898ac0b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff898ad1fa _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 304
15  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8e651cab _pthread_wqthread + 404
16  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8e63c171 start_wqthread + 13
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-install my old version of Aperture from DVD and then update to the latest version to fix the problem.